# iphone: show UIImagePicker in UIview

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a situation here please help me in this, can I show imagepicker in a view insted of presenting them in a modalview

I tried this code but it doesnt work

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;

picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
//[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[imagePickerView addSubview:picker.view];
```

Please shed some light on this
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController needs to be shown as modal, I think.. so I would uncomment that line.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html